# There's a formula for the order of the elements in $\mathbb{Z}/(n)\times \mathbb{Z}/(m)$?

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers

I would to have this formula and a demonstration of it.

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g\in\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\Leftrightarrow g=(g_m, g_n)$, where $g_m\in\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}, g_n\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, so one immediately has $g^{|g_m||g_n|}=(1, 1)$. It is not hard to check that $|g|=\text{lcm}(|g_m|, |g_n|)$.